# Select rows such that multiple columns have no duplicated values

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, duplicates

I have a data frame with these values(built in such a way):

```
id1 = (c(1,1,2,2))
id2 = (c(10,11,10,11))
value =c(50,50,50,50)
df = data.frame(id1,id2,value)

df : 
  value id1 id2
1    50   1  10
2    50   1  11
3    50   2  10
4    50   2  11
```

I would like to keep only rows where both id1 and id2 are unique(each value of id1 and id2 must appear only once),also there might be more then one duplicate of each id:

```
df_unique : 
value id1 id2
1    50   1  10
4    50   2  11
```

if I use the duplicated command on one of the columns and then the other,I would discard wanted rows.

A solution which will return (1,11) and (2,10) is also good,as long as each element in
id1 and id2 are unique.

Another example with more rows:

```
id1 = (c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3))
id2 = (c(10,11,12,10,11,12,10,11,12))
value =rep(50,9)
df = data.frame(id1,id2,value)

df:
  id1 id2 value
1   1  10    50
2   1  11    50
3   1  12    50
4   2  10    50
5   2  11    50
6   2  12    50
7   3  10    50
8   3  11    50
9   3  12    50
```

Where a good answer is:(1,10),(2,11),(3,12), but also any other answer where both id1 and id2 appear once are good.

Thank you,

Jacob

Comment: How do you decide whether 1,10; 2,11 is kept or can it be 1,11; 2,10?

Comment: In your example, both of those values appear twice. I don't understand your question.

Comment: simply doing "unique(df)" maybe.

Comment: Ananta - I edited the question (1,11) (2,10) are also good. Davide- unique(df) will return the same metrix since each row is unique

Comment: something like: `x <- lapply(df[, -1], duplicated); df[!xor(x$id1, x$id2), ]`

Comment: Arun - I have tried stuff like that the problem is that it works only for two duplication.

Comment: IIUC, before to do the step above, if you were to take the `unique` on `df` based on `id1, id2`, then it should work? That is: `df <- df[!duplicated(df[, c("id1", "id2")]), ]; x <- lapply(df[, c("id1", "id2")], duplicated); df[!xor(x$id1, x$id2), ]`. If you could provide an example where this breaks, it'd be easier to find out the issue and see if there's a fix.

Comment: Arun -Thank you for the help! I have added an example with three orders where your suggestion does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the data are arranged as in your example, cycling through `id2` for each value of `id1` and in the same order, the solution is easy:

```
N <- 3 # Number of rows in the result
idx <- seq(1, N*N, by=N) + seq(0,to=N-1)
df[idx,]
##   id1 id2 value
## 1   1  10    50
## 5   2  11    50
## 9   3  12    50
```

I doubt that this is what you're asking.  If the rows are in an unknown order or not all values are present in one column for each value in the other, you have to check each combination of N rows.

```
# Maximum number of result rows
N <- with(df, min(length(unique(id1)), length(unique(id2))))
N
## [1] 3

# Potential indices
index <- combn(seq(nrow(df)), N)
```

`index` is a matrix where each column represents three rows in `df`.  Now to check for duplicated values:

```
good <- apply(index, 2, function(x) !any(duplicated(df[x,'id1']) | duplicated(df[x,'id2'])))
```

`good` has the value `TRUE` for a combination of rows that passes the test.

```
which(good)
## [1] 22 24 39 44 53 56
index[, good]
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
## [1,]    1    1    2    2    3    3
## [2,]    5    6    4    6    4    5
## [3,]    9    8    9    7    8    7
```

Each column of the above matrix represents a combination of rows that passes the test.

This finds all the combinations.  You might want to find just the first combination, so that you don't go on to test additional combinations after a hit is found.  Then `for` is appropriate:

```
for (i in seq(ncol(index))) {
  x <- index[,i]
  if (!any(duplicated(df[x,'id1']) | duplicated(df[x,'id2']))) {
    rows <- x
    break
  }
}

df[rows,]
##   id1 id2 value
## 1   1  10    50
## 5   2  11    50
## 9   3  12    50
```

Note:  Depending on the data, it is possible that with `N=3`, you will get no rows that pass the test.  In that case, repeat the procedure with `N=2`, and so on.  I leave that loop as an exercise for the reader.